# Identify position of context node within another nodeset

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<Root>
    <Cover>
        <Cover_Ref Val="1"/>
        <Cover_Code Val="Food in transit"/>
        <AdditionalCover>
            <AdditionalCover_Area Val="Sussex"/>
        </AdditionalCover>
    </Cover>
    <Cover>
        <Cover_Ref Val="2"/>
        <Cover_Code Val="Frozen goods"/>
    </Cover>
    <Cover>
        <Cover_Ref Val="3"/>
        <Cover_Code Val="Business equipment"/>
        <AdditionalCover>
            <AdditionalCover_Area Val="Sussex"/>
        </AdditionalCover>
    </Cover>
    <AdditionalCoverResult>
        <CoverArea Val="Sussex"/>
        <CoverExcluded Val="N"/>
    </AdditionalCoverResult>
    <AdditionalCoverResult>
        <CoverArea Val="Sussex"/>
        <CoverExcluded Val="Y"/>
    </AdditionalCoverResult>
</Root>
```

I need to transform it into something like this:

```
<Insurances>
    <Insurance>
        <reference>1</reference>
        <CoverType>Food in transit</CoverType>
        <Region>Sussex</Region>
        <Excluded>N</Excluded>
    </Insurance>
    <Insurance>
        <reference>2</reference>
        <CoverType>Frozen goods</CoverType>
    </Insurance>
    <Insurance>
        <reference>3</reference>
        <CoverType>Business equipment</CoverType>
        <Region>Sussex</Region>
        <Excluded>Y</Excluded>
    </Insurance>
</Insurances>
```

The AdditionalCoverResult elements refer to Cover elements that contain AdditionalCover elements - so the first Cover element has its cover not excluded, while the third Cover element has its cover excluded. The second cover element does not have AdditionalCover, so there is no AdditionalCoverResult element that refers to it.

My problem is that within an `<xsl:for-each select="//Cover">` loop I can't think of a way of identifying which AdditionalCoverResult element I should be looking for. Using `position()` within the for-each ends up with me incorrectly outputting AdditionalCoverResult information for a Cover element that doesn't have AdditionalCover.

I have to preserve the original ordering of Cover, so I can't do two separate loops, one for Cover with AdditionalCover and one for Cover without AdditionalCover.

Within the nodeset returned by `//Cover` is there a way I can identify the context node's position within the nodeset returned by `//Cover[AdditionalCover]`?

I'm sort of guessing that for the Cover element I need to think "What index am I within `//Cover[AdditionalCover]` so that I can use that index to identify my corresponding AdditionalCoverResult element?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Insurances>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Cover"/>
  </Insurances>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Cover">
  <Insurance>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Insurance>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Cover_Ref">
  <reference><xsl:value-of select="@Val"/></reference>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Cover_Code">
  <CoverType><xsl:value-of select="@Val"/></CoverType>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="AdditionalCover_Area">
  <Region><xsl:value-of select="@Val"/></Region>

  <Excluded>
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "/*/AdditionalCoverResult[CoverArea/@Val=current()/@Val]
             [position()
             =
              1 +count(current()
                       /ancestor::Cover[1]
                          /preceding-sibling::Cover
                            [AdditionalCover
                              /AdditionalCover_Area/@Val
                            =
                             current()/@Val
                            ]
                      )
              ]
               /CoverExcluded/@Val
    "/>
  </Excluded>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Root>
    <Cover>
        <Cover_Ref Val="1"/>
        <Cover_Code Val="Food in transit"/>
        <AdditionalCover>
            <AdditionalCover_Area Val="Sussex"/>
        </AdditionalCover>
    </Cover>
    <Cover>
        <Cover_Ref Val="2"/>
        <Cover_Code Val="Frozen goods"/>
    </Cover>
    <Cover>
        <Cover_Ref Val="3"/>
        <Cover_Code Val="Business equipment"/>
        <AdditionalCover>
            <AdditionalCover_Area Val="Sussex"/>
        </AdditionalCover>
    </Cover>
    <AdditionalCoverResult>
        <CoverArea Val="Sussex"/>
        <CoverExcluded Val="N"/>
    </AdditionalCoverResult>
    <AdditionalCoverResult>
        <CoverArea Val="Sussex"/>
        <CoverExcluded Val="Y"/>
    </AdditionalCoverResult>
</Root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Insurances>
   <Insurance>
      <reference>1</reference>
      <CoverType>Food in transit</CoverType>
      <Region>Sussex</Region>
      <Excluded>N</Excluded>
   </Insurance>
   <Insurance>
      <reference>2</reference>
      <CoverType>Frozen goods</CoverType>
   </Insurance>
   <Insurance>
      <reference>3</reference>
      <CoverType>Business equipment</CoverType>
      <Region>Sussex</Region>
      <Excluded>Y</Excluded>
   </Insurance>
</Insurances>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the part of the current context you are interested in in a variables - so something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Cover">

  ...

  <xsl:variable name="additional" select="AdditionalCover/AdditionalCover_Area/@Val"/>
  <xsl:if select="$additional">
    <Excluded>
      <xsl:value-of select="AdditionalCoverResult[CoverArea/@Val = $additional]/CoverExcluded/@Val"/>
    </Excluded>
  </xsl:if>
</xs:for-each>
```

Comment: Hi Nick, the problem I have is that the CoverArea value for both Cover elements with AdditionalCover are the same - they're both "Sussex". Which is why I'm having to try to find the index of my context node within another node-set.

Answer (score 0):

After posting the question, I saw a link in the Related section - [xpath/xslt to determine index of context node relative to all nodes of same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527230/xpath-xslt-to-determine-index-of-context-node-relative-to-all-nodes-of-same-name)

Dimitre Novatchev's answer stated that by using

```
count(preceding::question)+1
```

You could find the current context node's index relative to all `question` elements in the document.

For my question I used `count(preceding::Cover[AdditionalCover])+1` and it worked - I'm hoping that I've understood it correctly but it does seem to do the trick.

I won't select this as the right answer immediately as I'd be very interested if anyone has any other ways of doing this - I'm probably intermediate level at XSLT and this is a great opportunity to learn some more about it!

Comment: You are almost there -- your current solution doesn't work in the general case where thate may be more than one different region that has different coverages. You may be interested to have a look at a complete and correct solution.